Dog bark classification
I have 3 h5 trained model 1st trained model to classify what breed , 2nd model for dog breed A bark classification and 3rd model for dog breed B bark classification. What I want is to classify first the breed of dog then if the dog will classified it will proceed to the corresponding model to classify the dog barks. Anyone can help! I'm using pycharm.
I'm using python pycharm and it takes 8mins before the classification starts.

What is your problem? Start time might be caused by loading the data or anything really. What did you already try?

It takes 8 minutes for the first classification before the result is displayed, however after the first classification, it will will classify smoothly . any suggestion to fix the problem that I encounter?

Did you check how long it takes to load only models without any predictions?

this is what iwant to classify
Load the breed classification model
breed_model_path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Pet Dog Bark Classification\Model\PetClassification.h5'
breed_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(breed_model_path)
Define class mappings for the breed classification model
breed_class_mapping = {
0: "Shih Tzu",
1: "Labrador Retriever",
2: "Not classified"
}
